# Cocoa automated WebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I looking into making a kind of robot testing browser. Like Selenium, but one that we can use to make full integration tests of our site. I'm wondering if it's possible to create a Cocoa app that loads up a web page in a WebView and they programmatically sends click events. I realize you could use:

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

To send js click evenets, but it would be better if you could send click events to the DOMElements themselves. That way you could test file uploads and other elements that can't be accessed via javascript like flash. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain DOMNode* objects corresponding exactly to JavaScript Node objects by using a `WebView`'s `-windowScriptObject` method (that returns the `WebScriptingObject*` that corresponds to the JavaScript `window` object) or any frame's `-DOMDocument` method to return that frame's JavaScript `document` method.

Example:

```
DOMDocument* d = [[webView mainFrame] DOMDocument];
[[[d getElementsByTagName:@"a"] item:0] click];
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Fake**](http://fakeapp.com/) sounds like exactly what you want.  It's WebKit based, automated, has tab support, and a huge library full of useful things like evaluating JavaScript, assertions, variables, events, and loops.  Highly recommended.

Comment: Good question!  I just tested this simple workflow with no problem: Load a URL, Set Value of HTML Element, and Submit HTML Form.  Uploaded a file to the server as expected (you can even drag-and-drop a file into the Value field in the workflow).